# Finding an XPATH expression

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath

For the following html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="first">AUD</td>
    <td> 0.00 </td>
    <td> 1,305.01 </td>
    <td> 1,305.01 </td>
    <td> -65.20 </td>
    <td> 0.00 </td>
    <td> 0.00 </td>
    <td> 1,239.81 </td>
    <td class="fx-rate"> 0.98542 </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to grab the value for the fx-rate, given the type of current. For example, the function would be something like `get_fx_rate(currency)`. This is the XPATH expression I have so far, but it results in an empty element, `[]`. What am I doing wrong here and what would be the correct expression?

```
"//td[@class='first']/text()[normalize-space()='AUD']/parent::td[@class='fx-rate']"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
//td[@class = 'first' and normalize-space() = 'AUD']/parent::tr/td[@class = 'fx-rate']
```

or clearer:

```
//tr[td[@class="first1" and normalize-space()="AUD"]]/td[@class="fx-rate"]
```

Comment: Definitely prefer the second expression. Much easier to read left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I managed to solve it, using partial xpaths:

```
### get all the elements via xpath
currencies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='first']")
fx_rates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='fx-rate']")

### build a list and zip it to get the k,v pairs
fx_values = [fx.text for fx in fx_rates if fx.text]
currency_text = [currency.text for currency in currencies if currency.text]
zip(currency_text,fx_values)[1:]
```